# Comparing a hash to an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashtable

I'm trying to compare a hash and an array for a test in ruby. The hash holds the values to be compared against, and the array holds the results to be tested. The array and the hash have the same number of elements, and the corresponding elements of the array should match those in the hash. For instance, the first slot of the array needs to match the first hash value, and then both the array and the hash should increment to the next value and array slot to see if they match. Basically, `hash[0]` and `array[0]` need to match, `hash[1]` and `array[1]` need to match, etc.

For example:

```
hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}

array = [100, 101, 102, 103]
```

`hash[0]` and `array[0]` need to match, if they don't it's an error. But I don't care if `hash[0]` matches with `array[1-3]` or if `array[0]` matches with `hash[1-3]`. `hash[1]` and `array[1]` need to match, but I don't care if `hash[1]` matches with `array[0, 2, 3]` or if `array[1]` matches with `hash[0, 2, 3]`. That is the gist of what I need.

Let's say I have this:

```
hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}

array = [100, 103, 102, 103]
```

`hash[1]` and `array[1]` don't match, so it's an error. But I don't care if `array[1]` and `hash[3]` match.

The issue I'm having with my code is that it goes through and compares the first hash value to ALL slots in the array when I only care about the corresponding ones (`hash[0]` and `array[0]`). How do I format my code to ONLY compare each corresponding hash value and array value (`hash[0]` and `array[0]`) before moving to the next pair (`hash[1]` and `array[1]`)?

This is what I have so far.

```
hash.each do |key, value|
 array.each do |slot|
  if slot.include? value
    puts "Key: #{key}"
    puts "Test Pass"
  else 
    puts "Test Fail"
  end 
 end
end
```

Comment: Do your hash and array contain the same number of elements?

Comment: How do `hash` and `array` look like? Post some example data, please, so the problem becomes more obvious.

Comment: I’d wild guess `hash.values == array`.

Comment: Looks like this will do `hash.values.sort == array.sort`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky: minus the sort.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why? `[1, 2] == [2, 1] # false`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky: similarly, it's not clear why you added it. It can lead to false positives.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky: "hash[0] and array[0] need to match" - note that it doesn't say that first value of the hash needs to match _any_ element of the array. Just whatever is at index 0.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes they contain the same number of elements

Comment: Is `hash` a Hash? You mean `hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}`?

Comment: @Stefan I updated my question, I hope that's helpful

Comment: @iGian yes you are correct, sorry about that

Comment: Try this `hash.transform_values.with_index { |k, idx| k - array[idx] }.map{ |k,v| k if v == 0}.compact` It should return matching keys. If I got the point.

Comment: Can you provide more inputs, including a pair that you expect to match, and a pair you expect not to match? I cannot tell whether your sample data matches or doesn't match. As far as I can tell from reading your question and follow up comments, you just want `hash.values.sort == array.sort`.

Comment: If your array and have have the same number of items, but you "don't care" if hash[1] matches array [0,2,3], that makes no sense. If they have the same number of items, then every item must match its corresponding item in the opposite structure and duplicates guarantee there will be no match.

Comment: @meagar I edited my question again I hope that's more clear

Comment: Then you simply want `hash.values == array`.

Comment: @meagar what exactly will that do?

Comment: It seems pretty clear what it will do, it will compare the values in the hash to the array. What part isn't clear?

Comment: @pjano1 "what exactly will that do" - the comparison you're after

Comment: Note that `.values` depends on the insertion order of the hash, which isn't relevant given your sample data. If your *real* data is different then `hash.values` won't work, and you'll need to clarify with more realistic data. Ideally you should include *actual Ruby*, the hash you've provided is definitely not syntactically correct Ruby code.

Comment: @pjano1 what do you mean by `hash[0]`? The hash value for key `0` (which doesn't exist in your example) or the value of the first key (the one at index 0) regardless of its key? Would `[100, 101, 102]` and `{foo: 100, bar: 101, baz: 102}` match?

Answer (score 1):

Given a hash...

```
hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}
```

You can get the values in that hash in *insertion order* using `.values`:

```
hash.values # => [100, 101, 102, 103]
```

A that point, you can use simple equality to test whether the values are equal to your array:

```
hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}
array = [100, 101, 102, 103]

hash.values == array # => true
```

This relies on the insertion order of the keys in your hash. Depending on how your hash is constructed, you may need to rely on the sort order of the keys, for example:

```
hash = {4 => 103, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 1 => 100 }
hash.values # => [103, 101, 102, 100]
```

If the intent is for the values to be ascending according to their corresponding keys, you can turn the hash into an array of `[key, value]` pairs, and sort based on the key:

```
hash = {4 => 103, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 1 => 100 }

hash.to_a                           # => [[4, 103], [2, 101], [3, 102], [1, 100]]
hash.to_a.sort(&:first) .           # => [[1, 100], [2, 101], [3, 102], [4, 103]]
hash.to_a.sort(&:first).map(&:last) # => [100, 101, 102, 103]

hash.to_a.sort(&:first).map(&:last) == array # => true
```

If your hash keys are always sequentially ascending numbers starting with `1`, then you can take a completely different approach and iterate over your array, and for each array index, compare the value at `hash[index + 1]`:

```
hash = {1 => 100, 2 => 101, 3 => 102, 4 => 103}
array = [100, 101, 102, 103]

array.each.with_index(1).all? { |item, index| item == hash[index] } # => true
```